# for loop in R to compute the yearly evolution of a variable

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, average, rate

here is the structure of my dataset for reproducibility :

```
structure(list(numero = c("133", "62", "75", "76", "86", "281"
), tranche_age = c("20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", 
"20-30"), tranche_anciennete = c("5 ans et moins", "5 à 10 ans", 
"5 ans et moins", "5 ans et moins", "5 à 10 ans", "5 à 10 ans"
), code_statut = c("C", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E"), code_contrat = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), taux_demploi_mois = c(100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100), echelon = c("E1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), niveau = c("N7", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), brut_mensuel = c(NA, 786.13, 1156.95, 1156.95, 
904.79, 904.79), estimation_annuelle = c(NA, 10219.69, 15040.35, 
15040.35, 11762.27, 11762.27), annee = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017), primes_en_montant = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), primes_en_pourcentage = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), brut_mensuel_ETP = c(NA, 
786.13, 1156.95, 1156.95, 904.79, 904.79)), row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
 "tbl", 
 "data.frame"))
```

Each worker is identified with one number ("numero"), which doesn't change from year to year. I would like to compute a new variable, to add to this dataframe, representing the evolution of the "estimation_annuelle" (which is the yearly wage) of each worker, from year to year (from 2017 to 2021), and then the average annual growth rate over the 5 years. Then, I would like to view those who have less than a 2% raise on one year (2017-2018 for example), and see whether it has been caught up in the following years or no (that is, if one's wage has increased by less than 2% between 2017 and 2018, if the wage increased one had between 2018 and 2019 compensated, and by how much, the insufficient raise on the previous yearly period).

I have tried a code to compute the variable evolution from year to year, which doesn't work :

```
test <- liste_complete %>%
   group_by(annee, numero) %>%
   select(numero, annee, estimation_annuelle)%>%
   data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(test$estimation_annuelle)) {
  print((test[i+1,] - test[i,])/test[i,])
}
```

And I have not found anything to compute the average annual growth rate (here is the formula : https://investinganswers.com/dictionary/a/average-annual-growth-rate-aagr), nor computed whether the insufficient increase for those who are concerned has been made up for in the following years.

Could anyone help ?

Comment: You data only shows `annee` of 2017. It will only be possible to verify solutions if you can include enough years to determine an answer, and for you to specify what answer you expect.

Comment: seems like liste_complete %>%
  group_by(numero) %>%
  arrange(annee, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(pct_change = (estimation_annuelle/lag(estimation_annuelle) -1) * 100) %>%
  select(numero, annee, niveau, estimation_annuelle, pct_change) 
works